# Paperclip fails when styles are applied - ImageMagick installed - Win 7 - Rails -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, imagemagick, paperclip

I've got paperclip working so that I can upload and edit a photo but when I try to apply styles to it it falls over.

> ```
> Invalid argument - convert
> ```

ImageMagick is installed but I'm not sure if it's installed properly - when I tested the install with the `convert logo: logo.gif` it creates the logo but I have to open it from explorer - it won't let me from the command line - as per instructions. (I'm not sure if this is an issue?)

```
  # Paperclip
    has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :thumb => "150x115>" }
```

If I rename the the ImageMagick folder I get a different error `undefined method "exitstatus"` which suggests to me that paperclip is talking to it but there's another issue?

---

Got it!!

Not sure what was going on but a system reboot sorted it. I suspect it had something to do with ImageMagick setting it's root path. I had re-installed it several times trying to get it to work.

Comment: It seems that Paperclip doesn't require this line anymore?
I tried it with several different file paths and it seemed to have no effect. It's working now without the line.

On my travels I found comments that said IM needs to be in a file path WITHOUT spaces - as it default installs in /Program Files/ this may have been the problem, but this issue may have been fixed? It's now in C:/ImageMagick/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows 7, but can definitely confirm that it has to do with the installation of  ImageMagick, and nothing to do with how you've used the paperclip gem.

Once ImageMagick is installed correctly, you should be able to run the `convert` command from Cygwin.

Did you run the installer [from here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)?

Comment: Yes. I ran the default ImageMagick-6.7.2-7-Q16-windows-dll.exe.

Comment: I have been running the command from the windows cmd not cygwin. 
I installed cygwin and tried to run the command convert logo: logo.miff which produces a permission denied error. I allowed my user account full permissions in the imagemagick folder and the convert.exe with the same result.

I have to admit I'm fumbling in the dark here. Any ideas?

Running imdisplay /images/logo.png from cygwin (which did nothing from the windows cmd) opens the ImageMagick shell but not the image...